# Download file from password protected directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, download, password-protection

I'm using vb.net and need to download a file (from a given URL). The problem is that the directory is password protected. (Using standard .htpasswd)

If this is not possible using vb.net then please suggest an alternative solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35787/VB-NET-Background-File-Downloader) to download a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain why you would password protect a directory if you then want to allow users to download files from it without entering a password. However, you could write an ASHX that takes the filename as a querystring parameter and serves the download for the requested file.

Comment: Would ASHX work if I don't have control of the website? I am the end user.